# Web server with OpenSSL

Tags: c, linux, ssl, tcp

I was trying to compile my web server, but these things like below happened:

```
gcc -o webserv.o webserv.c -c -ansi -pedantic -Wall -lssl -lcrypto
webserv.c: In function ‘main’:
webserv.c:33: warning: ‘OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/evp.h:828)
webserv.c:34: warning: ‘SSL_load_error_strings’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1416)
webserv.c:36: warning: ‘TLSv1_server_method’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1520)
webserv.c:38: warning: ‘SSL_CTX_new’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1346)
webserv.c:40: warning: ‘ERR_print_errors_fp’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/err.h:287)
webserv.c:44: warning: ‘SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1402)
webserv.c:45: warning: ‘SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1401)
webserv.c:47: warning: ‘SSL_CTX_check_private_key’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1475)
webserv.c:92: warning: ‘SSL_new’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1481)
webserv.c:94: warning: ‘ERR_print_errors_fp’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/err.h:287)
webserv.c:98: warning: ‘SSL_set_fd’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1370)
webserv.c:100: warning: ‘SSL_accept’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1491)
webserv.c:102: warning: ‘ERR_print_errors_fp’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/err.h:287)
webserv.c:106: warning: ‘SSL_get_version’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1502)
webserv.c:106: warning: ‘SSL_CIPHER_get_name’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1360)
webserv.c:106: warning: ‘SSL_get_current_cipher’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1357)
webserv.c:114: warning: ‘SSL_shutdown’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1532)
webserv.c:116: warning: ‘SSL_free’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1490)
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: -lssl: linker input file unused because linking not done
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: -lcrypto: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc -o helper.o helper.c -c -ansi -pedantic -Wall -lssl -lcrypto
helper.c: In function ‘Readline’:
helper.c:32: warning: ‘SSL_read’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1493)
helper.c: In function ‘Writeline’:
helper.c:68: warning: ‘SSL_write’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1495)
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: -lssl: linker input file unused because linking not done
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: -lcrypto: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc -o servreq.o servreq.c -c -ansi -pedantic -Wall -lssl -lcrypto
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: -lssl: linker input file unused because linking not done
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: -lcrypto: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc -o reqhead.o reqhead.c -c -ansi -pedantic -Wall -lssl -lcrypto
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: -lssl: linker input file unused because linking not done
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: -lcrypto: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc -o resphead.o resphead.c -c -ansi -pedantic -Wall -lssl -lcrypto
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: -lssl: linker input file unused because linking not done
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: -lcrypto: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc -o resource.o resource.c -c -ansi -pedantic -Wall -lssl -lcrypto
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: -lssl: linker input file unused because linking not done
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: -lcrypto: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc -o webserv webserv.o helper.o servreq.o reqhead.o resphead.o resource.o -Wall -lssl -lcrypto
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_server_ssl", referenced from:
      _Readline in helper.o
      _Writeline in helper.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Anybody knows what is wrong here?**

Comment: based on this line: warning: ‘OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/openssl/evp.h:828) webserv.c:34: 
Your OPENSSL is deprecated, I recommend you update your system, but of course if you provide more information we can check deeply what is going on ...

Comment: Welcome to SO, please format your code/text output next time (see `{}` button in the editor).

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your compiler is set to abort linking on warnings, and the compile phase generated dozens of "deprecation" warnings in your code. So, either change the compiler flags or update the deprecated calls would seem to be your options.

Comment: But it seems that lots of people use the same function calls too. Online tutorials also introduced the same function calls to deal with OpenSSl

Comment: Looks like there was/is a deprecation/ expiration issue with some certain versions of OpenSSL. See this (somewhat old) thread for a representative discussion: http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-ports/2010-January/058899.html